# .NET Maui Mopups - Loading popup not showing up when using navigationpage

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, maui

I have a popup to show while loading screens. When using a NavigationPage as MainPage, when I try to show my popup on top all pages it is sent to the back while pushing a new page. Is there a way to make it appear in front of everything ?

For example:

I show my loading popuppage

`await MopupService.Instance.PushAsync(new Popups.Popup_Loading());`

After that call im pushing in the nav stack my popup goes to the background

`await Navigation.PushAsync(new Soporte.Page_Tickets_General("New"));`

Im trying to get my popup on top of all the nav stack pages, but no results.

In windows is working as I want to, buy Android is the one that has this behavior

Comment: I don't think you're able to show a popup that remains on top during a page navigation

Comment: Im trying to replicate Xamarin Forms flow with RG.Plugins.Popup and MasterDetailPage. But nothing seems to work